# UK train strike: London Heathrow to Cambridge travel

Tags: uk, trains, lhr, event-based-effects, cambridge

So looks like all of UK rail is on strike tomorrow 27th July Wed. According to the National rail website partial service is available on some routes.

It shows London to Cambridge as one such. But i am curious what's the reality usually. Do trains actually run or would it be pretty difficult to get to Cambridge?

Looks like London Underground is not on strike so i should be able to take picadally line to Liverpool Street. The challange is whether the National rail would run from there to Cambridge or not.

PS. Is there a way to know the live train status from London to Cambridge so i can decide at Heathrow itself what my options will be?

Comment: There are three rail routes from London to Cambridge. Abellio Greater Anglia runs a service from Liverpool Street Station, Great Northern runs a service from Kings Cross Station, and Thameslink runs from St Pancras Station. If you are using the London Underground, Kings Cross / St Pancras is best *if trains are running*. Note that the Picadilly line does not go to Liverpool Street (which has an inferior train service to Cambridge too): there is no direct tube line from Heathrow to Liverpool Street.

Comment: There are really only two (sane, significantly distinct) routes. The great Northern and Thameslink services are not Significatly distinct. Great Northern and Thameslink are brands of the same operator and the trains take basically the same route.

Comment: "*there is no direct tube line from Heathrow to Liverpool Street*" there is now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can be pretty confident that they'll run the service they currently say - [National Rail Enquiries for 27/07/22 midday shows the strike timetable](https://ojp.nationalrail.co.uk/service/timesandfares/London/CBG/270722/1200/dep)

That's a major route that will be prioritised for the short operating hours.  They seem to be planning to operate most services in the middle of the day on that route, comparing tomorrow to Thursday, though at slightly shifted times.

Having said that, I don't plan to trust them as I'd be getting the penultimate or even the last train to Bristol from Cardiff and don't have a plan B.

Live departure boards for the next 2 hours are found via  https://www.nationalrail.co.uk/times_fares/ldb.aspx

Specifically for your journey, you can bookmark: [from King's Cross to Cambridge](https://ojp.nationalrail.co.uk/service/ldbboard/dep/KGX/CBG/To) and [from St Pancras to Cambridge](https://ojp.nationalrail.co.uk/service/ldbboard/dep/STP/CBG/To) - they're adjacent and served by the same tube station but have different services.

In the recent strikes, at least on the South Wales line, they did manage to stick to their greatly reduced timetable, with fairly normal delays.

Comment: Your answer is unclear. You say "... _not_ for 27 July 2022..." The [National Rail page you cite](https://ojp.nationalrail.co.uk/service/timesandfares/London/CBG/tomorrow/1200/dep), however, contains this text in the red-colored drop-down at the top: "Industrial Action to affect services across Britain on 27 July and 30 July." The NR text sounds exactly like tomorrow, which (as we write) is 27 July.  It would be useful if you would amend your answer to resolve this apparent conflict.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I struggled to word that. Check the url and it includes "tomorrow". Set a future date, change the url to tomorrow's date, and it fails. I'll try to change it but there's no compact way to say it

Comment: But (@DavidSupportsMonica) that red warning is a red herring in the context of my answer. It shows up on any visit to the national rail website. So I've said nothing about that in the answer, and will say nothing about it. I discuss the timetables

Comment: Well...I'm still confused. Your answer says "...note that this is for "tomorrow", **not for 27 July 2022**. The NR warning applies, as far as I can see, to July 27 and July 30. Referring to specific dates, not words where the meaning changes depending on the date the words are read, would be clearer.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, it is not for a given date, it is for the day after you check the information.  So when you check it on 26 July 2022, it will show 27 July 2022. But when you check it on 27 July 2022, it will show the information for 28 July 2022.

Comment: @Willeke Yes, that's so. My issue is that the answer refers to a relative date ("tomorrow"), whose meaning changes depending upon when the relative date is written or read. Ordinal dates (e.g., "July 27") don't change. The answer's use of a relative date makes this issue confusing.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica in the context  of this answer **ignore the warning**.  The strike is 27th and 30th, as warned, but it would appear at the top of the page if I tried to search for trains on Christmas day. **I'm not talking about the warning**. I'm talking about the strike day timetable.  If you want to go on about the warning, you'll have to write your own answer.  I will try to address the difficulty of describing a link that *has to be to a relative date* (because that's all the website supports), in the context of an absolute date.  I chose words to match the source.

Comment: selecting 28th July and then changing the date to 27 in the URL seems to work for me...? https://ojp.nationalrail.co.uk/service/timesandfares/London/CBG/270722/1200/dep

Comment: @JakeDot strange, I got a 404 when I tried that

Comment: Went like clockwork. Thanks. :)